# How to get results from PDF file to Android app?

Tags: android, pdf

I am working in a bank project where I have a lots of PDF files stored online containing information of user bank account where data is in the form of tables.
I want to create an app where a user can get his information on the app by just entering there bank account number.

My question is there any way to access the data through online without downloading those PDF files on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Without downloading , your data will not be able to access, as you can see in other banking applications, first you need to bring that data into raw format or original text format, then you can easily access the data using a network call.

Comment: I can convert the data from pdf to excel using adobe acrobat ! So should i convert excel to sqlite database or is there any way to access data from excel sheets directly?

Comment: yes.. you can do it..i havent tried but you can get an idea from http://www.cuelogic.com/blog/creatingreading-an-excel-file-in-android/

Comment: i am thinking of creating a sqlite database and storing it online. I think that will be more efficient.